# How can I update CFileView tree in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I generated a new MFC project which is a MDI with Ribbon bar and explorer docking pane(`CFileView` class) by Visual Studio 2015.

I make a code which can select the specific files in my harddisk drive by using `CFileDialog` class and save the file names in a `CString` vector which located in C*App class.

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzVxw.png)

However, I cannot get how to put this file names into the tree for display after I select the files. At first, I just modified the `FillFileView()` class in the `CFileView` class, and no error detected. However, when I execute the code, an error message appears.

[Variable declaration & Source code & Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Bam.png)

Please answer to my question how to fix this.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text instead of posting text.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file Names are in a vector, can you try manually iterating over the vector & populating your Tree control? CTreeCtrl has an InsertItem() method.